# JavaScript populate data dynamically into HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I am trying to populate table cells with data dynamically. I followed this [JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4pEJB/).

Here is my code:

```
var heading = new Array();
        heading[0] = "Type"
        heading[1] = "Item Name"
        heading[2] = "Brand"
        heading[3] = "Unit Price"
        heading[4] = "Quantity"

        var stock = new Array();
        for(var i = 0; i < topProductList.length; i++){
            stock[0].push(topProductList[i].type);
            stock[1].push(topProductList[i].itemName);
            stock[2].push(topProductList[i].brand);
            stock[3].push(topProductList[i].unitprice);
            stock[4].push(topProductList[i].quantity);

            console.log(topProductList[i].type + ' ' + topProductList[i].itemName + ' ' + topProductList[i].brand + ' ' + topProductList[i].unitprice + ' ' + topProductList[i].quantity);
        }
```

I tried to add the data for each column by looping through my array. However, I am getting `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. I printed out the `console.log` to check if I am retrieving correctly and the data retrieval has no problem. It is just that the part when I tried to add each data into column is encountering problem.

Any ideas?

Sample data for the topProductList:

```
var topProductList = [{type: 'home appliance', name: 'Sound Teoh Tv Cable 5m Hl3599 Soundteoh', unitprice: 9.90, quantity: 5},
{type: 'kitchen appliance', name: ' Powerpac Mini Rice Cooker Pprc09 Powerpac', unitprice: 19.90, quantity: 5},
{type: 'kitchen appliance', name: ' Sona 2-slice Bread Toaster Sto2201 Sona', unitprice: 39.90, quantity: 5},
{type: 'home appliance', name: ' Simply Living. 10" Wall Clock Simply Living', unitprice: 9.90, quantity: 5},
{type: 'kitchen appliance', name: ' Morries Pie Maker Ms-8028pm Morries', unitprice: 29.90, quantity: 4}];
```

Comment: Sample data for the topProductList is an invalid JSON as you didn't close the single quote for name key, I have updated the JSON ... Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stock` variable is an array but not the `stock[0]`;

just do

```
stock.push();
```

or directly set that value on index on as-

```
stock[0] = topProductList[i].type;
```

** Edit after comments **

looks like your stock is a multi dimension array. In that case, if you are follow along with jsfiddle example, just do as-

```
stock[0] = new Array(topProductList[i].type);
```

Comment: If I changed it to stock[0] = topProductList[i].type; , it becomes the result as per the screenshot I just added. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeap that does the trick. I realized should replace the index with i instead. It's solved now thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `push` for an array element. However, you can use `push` with an array. Please check [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a http://jsfiddle.net/4pEJB/488/

```js
function addTable() {
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("metric_results")
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')

    table.border = '1'
    table.appendChild(tableBody);

    var heading = new Array();
    heading[0] = "Type"
    heading[1] = "Item Name"
    heading[2] = "Unit Price"
    heading[3] = "Quantity"


    var stock = new Array()
    var topProductList = [{type: 'home appliance', name: 'Sound Teoh Tv Cable 5m Hl3599 Soundteoh', unitprice: 9.90, quantity: 5},
{type: 'kitchen appliance', name: ' Powerpac Mini Rice Cooker Pprc09 Powerpac', unitprice: 19.90, quantity: 5},
{type: 'kitchen appliance', name: ' Sona 2-slice Bread Toaster Sto2201 Sona', unitprice: 39.90, quantity: 5},
{type: 'home appliance', name: ' Simply Living. 10" Wall Clock Simply Living', unitprice: 9.90, quantity: 5},
{type: 'kitchen appliance', name: ' Morries Pie Maker Ms-8028pm Morries', unitprice: 29.90, quantity: 4}];
    

     for(var i = 0; i < topProductList.length; i++){
        var temp = [];
        temp.push(topProductList[i].type);
        temp.push(topProductList[i].name);
        temp.push(topProductList[i].unitprice);
        temp.push(topProductList[i].quantity);
        stock.push(temp);
     }

    //TABLE COLUMNS
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    for (i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement('TH')
        th.width = '75';
        th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(heading[i]));
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    //TABLE ROWS
    for (i = 0; i < stock.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        for (j = 0; j < stock[i].length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(stock[i][j]));
            tr.appendChild(td)
        }
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    }  
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
}
```

```html
<div id="metric_results">
    <input type="button" id="create" value="Click here" onclick="Javascript:addTable()">
</div>
```

You need to push a value (array) to stock by
`stock.push("abc");`

Your `stock` variable in an `array` of `array`. **Inner** `array` contains **column level data**, where as **outer** `array` is **row level data**.

One more way to reduce the number of lines of code, replace the for loop by below code.

```
var keys = Object.keys(topProductList[0]);
 for(var i = 0; i < topProductList.length; i++){
   var temp = [];
   for(var key in keys){
    temp.push(topProductList[i][keys[key]]);
   }
   stock.push(temp);
 }
```

Comment: But the data inside topProductList is row by row. I have updated the question. With the code suggested, the table is not populating anything

Comment: Yeap this works too. Thanks so mcuh! Although I used the suggestion from Fazal and made some modification to make it one liner to loop for all. :)

Comment: @EmmaHannah ... Check the edited answer of mine. Instead of specifying each key, you can get the keys & loop over the keys. Even in the future number of column increases you don't have to change the code..

Comment: Cool I think I will use the version of yours as it supports extensibility. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

`stock[0]` is undefined you need to initialize your array like this

```
var stock = [ [], [], [], [], [], [] ];
```